# Grothendieck categories are complete

Tags: abelian-categories

I've been reading a book on triangulated categories and derived categories. The writer supposes that the readers are familiar with Grothendieck categories. He lists several basic properties. The one disturbs me is that a Grothendieck category is complete. The writer refers to the book [Abelian Categories Murfet](http://therisingsea.org/notes/AbelianCategories.pdf)
for the proof. Murfet writes before Theorem 22:

> Proofs of the following results can be found in any decent reference
> on category theory.

But I failed to find such one.

Comment: To show that a category is complete, it is enough to show that it has products and equalizers. This is shown in every textbook on category theory. You have equalizers because you have kernels. And you have products because you do.

Comment: How to get products？Grothendieck categories do have coproducts, but what about products? How to construct products?

Comment: To me, a gentle-ish exposition of this (and the fact that a Grothendieck category has enough injectives) seems to be included in Bo Stenström's book *Rings of quotients*.

Comment: @PavelČoupek Thanks. This book seems to have the same content as Mitchell's book. The proof of completeness is excluded.

Comment: @user12580 It is included, although it is probably not as straightforward as I thought: in chapter X, it is shown that any Grothendieck category can be considered to be a reflective subcategory  (even Giraud subcategory) of some category $\mathrm{Mod}-R,$ and that any such category is complete and cocomplete (chapter X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grothendieck categories are [locally presentable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category), and it's a more general fact that although locally presentable categories are only required to be cocomplete, the other axioms imply that they are in fact complete.

This follows from the fact that locally presentable categories satisfy a very strong form of the [adjoint functor theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem): any functor between locally presentable categories that preserves colimits has a right adjoint. Now apply this result to the diagonal functor $C \to C^J$, where $C$ is locally presentable and $J$ is a (small) diagram.

For a reference see Corollary 5.2.8 in Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra Vol. II* although the proof given there is different.

Comment: I am not familiar with the theory of sheaves and your answer encourages me to learn it. So I accept your answer without checking it. Thank you!!

Comment: One more question…since I 've gone through the first three chapters of Mitchell's book Theory of Categories, I know that grothendieck categories have enough injective objects ,an injective cogenerators and are locally and colocally small. Are they helpful?

Comment: Unfortunately, Grothendieck categories being locally presentable is not very obvious: most authors attribute it to Gabriel-Popescu theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to invoke Gabriel-Popescu embedding theorem here.

The fact essentially follows from Special Adjoint Functor Theorem.

> **Special Adjoint Functor Theorem (SAFT).** Let $F\colon\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{D}$ be a continuous functor with $\mathsf{C}$ being complete well-powered category with a cogenerating set. Then $F$ admits a left adjoint.

The proof can be found in many places, such as Mac Lane or Borceux.

From this the following proposition can be deduced:

> Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a complete well-powered category with a cogenerating set. Then $\mathsf{C}$ is a cocomplete.

The proof uses the fact that a category $\mathsf{C}$ admits all $\mathsf{I}$-shaped colimits if and only if the diagonal functor $\Delta\colon \mathsf{C}\to [\mathsf{I},\mathsf{C}]$ (which maps an object to its constant functor and a morphism to its constant natural transformation) has a left adjoint (which would be the colimit functor).

Then the claim that Grothendieck categories are complete follows from the dual of the above proposition (for Grothendieck categories being co-well-powered, there's an easy theorem that abelian categories are well-powered if and only of they are co-well-powered).