# Grothendieck categories are locally presentable

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, locally-presentable-categories

The way I've read it, many fundamental facts about Grothendieck categories, such as completeness, are special cases of those about locally presentable categories (see, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1904650/229776) answer).

However, it doesn't seem that obvious that Grothendieck categories are locally presentable. Is there a reference proving that? [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_category) on Grothendieck categories says that it is a consequence of Gabriel-Popescu theorem. Surely, there must be an easier way to show that?

Comment: I'm not sure there needs to be an easier proof - although I'd be glad to see it if there is. The main obstruction is finding a good $\lambda$ and enough $\lambda$-compact objects. For instance proving that your generator is $\lambda$-compact for some $\lambda$ would probably be enough; but I can't immediately see a good way to do that

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Have you yourself went through the proof of Gabriel-Popescu? If yes, what source would you suggest?

Comment: No I haven't, although I did see an outline on Akhil Mathew's blog, here : https://amathew.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/the-gabriel-popescu-theorem-and-a-variant-of-kuhn/